# Z3 opt-context in the opt-branch

Tags: optimization, z3

I have a rather specific question about using the optimization features of the Z3 opt-branch.

Namely, I can add assertions to the "opt" context using `z3_optimize_assert`, and those constraints do work.
However, all constraints added to the original `z3_context`, which was used to create the optimization context are ignored.
Is it a bug or a feature? What is the purpose of having two contexts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only function that adds constraints to the context is called Z3_assert_cnstr.
It is a deprecated function. You should assert constraints to the engine that you want to use.
There are now the following engines:

```
 Z3_solver_assert
 Z3_fixedpoint_assert
 Z3_optimzie_assert
 Z3_goal_assert
```

Assertions are local to the solver, fixed-point context, optimize context or goal, respectively.